# Facebook comments plugin not displaying moderation link

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I'm using the Facebook comments box plugin..I have many pages with different get urls (example.com/id.php?id=1,example.com/id.php?id=2), and I'm attempting to give each its own seperate comments box. Everything is working fine except I get a warning telling me to add the href to the like button so I did. The only problem is, now a moderation link doesn't even appear..Here's code
    "      href="example.com/example.php?id="> ...I also included all meta tags I'm 100% sure..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem..Basically, if the page requires a login of some sort to view the contents, Facebook's bots don't have access to the meta tags.Therefore, you should add the meta tags to the page that a non-logged in user would see..This really caused me trouble and I hope this helps someone!